# jQuery UI Sortable: Log origin and destination when dragging elements between columns

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I need that, when moving Sortable elements between columns, the previous column and the column into which the element is being dragged, both get logged, and to be able to register this change.

As you can see I tried to send 'My parent has changed' to console whenever destination column's data-priority attribute doesnt match attribute of the original column, and to add updated class to the dragged element, but to no avail, so perhaps Im doing something wrong?

It seems the variable rootParent is set as both the original column data-priority attr, as well as the new column's, which is not what I want

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.quadrants').sortable({
    connectWith: '.quadrants',
    cursor: 'move',
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    update: function(e, ui) {
      var rootParent = $(e.target).attr('data-priority');
      console.log(rootParent);
      $(this).children().each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).parent().attr('data-priority') != rootParent) {
          console.log('My parent has changed');
          $(this).addClass('updated');
        }
      });
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.quadrants {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1.5px solid #d4dce2;
  min-height: 160px !important;
  padding: 3px !important;
}
.quadrants>div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px !important;
  background: #C1FFF8;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.updated{
  background: #FFD2C1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container row">
  <div class="quadrants col-xs-3" data-priority="1">
    <div>
      Draggable
    </div>
    <div>
      Draggable
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="quadrants col-xs-3" data-priority="2">
    <div>
      Draggable
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="quadrants col-xs-3" data-priority="3">
    <div>
      Draggable
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on using Sortable by itself to get column attributes and used Droppable instead, in combination with Sortable to get a log of element ordering inside columns

```
$( ".quadrants" ).droppable({
      accept: ".tasks",
      drop: function( e, ui ) {
        var draggedElement = ui.draggable;
        var newColumn = [];
        newColumn.push([draggedElement.attr('data-index'), $(e.target).attr('data-priority')]);
        console.log(newColumn);
        console.log('My parent changed');
      }
    });

  $('.quadrants').sortable({
    connectWith: '.quadrants',
    cursor: 'move',
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    update: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).children().each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).parent().attr('data-priority') != index+1) {
          $(this).attr('data-position', (index+1)).addClass('updated');
          console.log('My position changed');
        }
      });
    }

  });
```